# How much time does it take for an app to be available in the App Store

Tags: iphone, ios

After submiting a new application, will it be instantly available for purchasing, or does it take some dealy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I give to clients and is generally the case for apps we have submitted from the UK (over 75 apps and hundreds of updates) is "between 1 and 4 weeks".

This is usually the scenario but there is a lot left up to chance.

You can also apply for extenuating circumstances (say for instance if your app needs to be released for a specific event ie. the World Cup) when I have seen apps get reviewed in a matter of days. You will not always be successful in receiving this benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be instantly available, since Apple has to look at your app first. They will check your app and accept it or reject it accordingly. It depends of course, on how long it takes until your app is reviewed. It has to be done by humans so I believe the time it'll take differs per app.

Comment: have you submitted any? how long did it take?

Comment: I hear different sounds. Sometimes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189952/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-an-app-approved-for-the-appstore), it can take 3 weeks. Sometimes more or less. Like said in the other thread, it depends on how advanced your app is...